# Return table from mySQL with a selected option from the database value

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a task management website in php that returns a mySQL table; the main meat of this is shown below:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $formatissuedate . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["issuer"] . "            </td>" . "<td>" . $row["task"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $row["responsibility"] . "</td>" . "<td>" . $formatduedate . "</td>" . "**<td>" . $row["status"] . "</td>**    </tr>";
```

However what I would like to do is for the: `<td>" . $row["status"] . "</td>` 
area is to have a drop down which contains the options="completed","started" and "not started" and for the selected option to be the value from mySQL `($row["status"])`.

I have no idea how to do this. Once I get this sorted out I will write some jquery so that when this value changes to write back to the mySQL database with the updated value. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: So start with inserting `<select ...` in a proper place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below ought to give you some idea how to proceed. If these records are created within a loop ( ie: recordset iteration ) then you can define the array `$options` before the loop starts.

```
<?php
    /* Assume this is in a loop? Also, assumed a record called `id` */
    $status=$row['status'];
    $options=array('completed','started','not started');

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>" . $formatissuedate . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["issuer"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["task"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $row["responsibility"] . "</td>
            <td>" . $formatduedate . "</td>
            <td>
                <select name='status_{$row['id']}'>";

    foreach( $options as $key ){
        $selected=( $key==$status ) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo "<option value='{$key}'{$selected}>{$key}";    
    }

    echo "          
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>";
?>
```

Comment: Just a follow up question, on the line of code here:
<select name='status_{$row['id']}'>";
I believe you are trying to put the row ID as the select name, but for some reason this part isn't working...any ideas? It just has the name "status_"

Comment: Sorry I resolved this myself, I forgot to put the id in the select statement!

Comment: sorry, been asleep - glad you figured that out ~ it ws mentioned in the comment at the top of the script '-) The inclusion of the `id` is probably not so important if you intend to use jQuery to update the db - quite easy to find the relevant records in the table-row

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
 <select>
   <option value="completed" <?php echo $row["status"] == "completed" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Completed</option>
   <option value="started" <?php echo $row["status"] == "started" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Started</option>
   <option value="not started" <?php echo $row["status"] == "not started" ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Not started</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a code like following if you have only a few and fixed-list of options:

```
$statusList = array(0 => 'Disabled', 1 => 'Enabled');

echo '<select name="status">';
foreach($statusList as $statusId => $statusName) {
    $selected   = ($statusId == $row["status"]) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo '<option value="'.$statusId.'"'.$selected.'>'.$statusName.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

If you have several options in your drop-down or your options are likely to change over time, it will be better to create a separate database table for them.